# How do I make sure the window size is always reset after a resize in selenium?

Tags: ruby, selenium, selenium-webdriver, capybara

I have a selenium test that I have that needs to be done with the window at a certain size. I have figured out how to set the window size, but I need to make sure that it always gets reset when I am done. My question is two fold.

1. How do I reset the window to the default size.
2. How do I make sure that the reset ALWAYS runs, even if the test fails. Can I use "rescue"?

   ```
   def test_nav_mobile
      page.visit "/foo/bar"
      page.driver.browser.manage.window.resize_to(500,500)
      #Perform the test...
      #Resize here?
   end
   ```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do the following:

```
def test_nav_mobile
  # Store the original height/width
  orig_height = page.driver.browser.manage.window.size.height
  orig_width = page.driver.browser.manage.window.size.width

  # Do stuff at smaller browser size
  page.visit "/foo/bar"
  page.driver.browser.manage.window.resize_to(500,500)
  #Perform the test...

ensure
  # Resize browser back to original size
  page.driver.browser.manage.window.resize_to(orig_height,orig_width)
end
```

A couple of notes:

1. You want to use `ensure` to make sure the resizing to original always occurs - ie if there is an exception or no exception. Using `rescue` would mean that you only want the line to run if something goes wrong.
2. I do not think there is any default size, so you can just store the dimensions at the start of the test and then resize back to them at the end.